# How to know the logic of HP Fortify rules for .Net?

Tags: .net, fortify

I want to write and equivalent of HP Fortify rule in FXCop, for that first I want to see and understand the existing Rules in Fortify, How do i Do that?

Comment: The rules are not viewable, but some of them are pretty easy to understand. FXCop isn't as capable as Fortify so you can't really recreate data flow issues like SQL Injection or XSS. You can look for semantic and control flow issues though.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Fortify rulepack are located at ~FORTIFY_INSTALL_DIR\Core\config\rules directory with .bin extension. These are the business secrets so you cannot deep dive on them. For 2015Q4 rulepack, there are 835,000+ inspection APIs in 691 issue categories across 22 programming languages, each API is represented by a RULEGUILD, which you can see the number at the lower left bottom of the FPR report.

[image]

(2) You can write custom rule by using ~FORTIFY_INSTALL_DIR\bin\CustomRulesEditor.cmd, select language .NET
[image]

Then select a rule template that fits your need, tweak the details to create the custome rule. A sample custom rule can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804202/hp-fortify-validation-rules-on-path-manipulation)

(3) To check if rules are properly applied, open FPR in AWB, "click center pane -> Project Summary -> Analysis Information tab -> Security Content" to view the rule versions